# Infinite dimensional and eigenvectors?

Tags: functional-analysis

In the proof of lemma 60 below, ($G$ is a compact Lie group)

It says if it is not finite dimensional, then it contains a sequence of orthogonal eigenvectors,
and we could get an convergent subsequence in its image, but it can't and hence got contradiction.

Why is it related to infinite dimensional? If it is finite, why can't we pick such sequence?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation indicates this is an *infinite* sequence of orthonormal eigenvectors. Many people restrict the word "sequence" to infinite ones in this way.

Comment: The notation is not clear-do you mean $y_i$ are $\lambda_i$-eigenvectors? And how do your $c_i$ depend on $n$? In any case all your $x_n$ must be elements of the finite-dimensional vector space spanned by the $y_i$, and so they certainly can't all be orthogonal. They won't all be eigenvectors, either.